# Display playback controls in AVPlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I am able to run the video, but I am not able to see the control buttons like pause and the slider to interact with the video. Similar query is asked ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33677527/avplayer-with-playback-controls-of-avplayerviewcontroller)) but I do not follow the answer.

Comment: I would suggest to use awesome tutorial & demo available in [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVPlayerDemo/Introduction/Intro.html) It has all the controls you are looking for

Comment: Thank you Dipen, I had seen this example and it is very useful one but it doesn't use AVPlayerViewController which uses system playback controls.

Comment: its not AVPlayerViewController, its pure `AVPlayer` example. Please do check again.

Comment: Yes thats what I meant, it is pure AVPlayer example. I want a one with system playback controls ( done using AVPlayerViewCntroller ) which is very well explained in [WWDC 2014](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/503/)

Comment: Then you should use `MPMoviePlayerController` thats the only one which gives your desired result.

Comment: `MPMoviePlayerController` is deprecated from iOS9.0. I think `AVPlayerViewController` does the same job as the `MPMoviePlayerController` does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the answer with description. [See here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IOS_8_Video_Playback_using_AVPlayer_and_AVPlayerViewController). To display system playback controls like play, pause button etc. we need AVPlayerViewController.
Below is the implementation in Objective-C.

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong,nonatomic) AVPlayerViewController *avPlayerViewController;
@property (strong,nonatomic) AVPlayer *avPlayer;
@end
```

---

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //URL for the file. It can be over HTTP or local file URL. 
    NSURL *folderURL=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:uploadFolderLocation];
    NSURL *movieURL=[folderURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"video.mp4"];

    self.avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:movieURL];

    self.avPlayerViewController=[[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];
    self.avPlayerViewController.player=self.avPlayer;    
}
```

---

```
- (IBAction)playButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    //Trigger the video to play

    //AVPlayer object can direct its visual output to AVPlayer. AVPlayerVC is a AVPlayerViewController. You can add it via objects in bottom-right corner.
    AVPlayerVC *avPLayerVC=[[AVPlayerVC alloc] init];
    avPLayerVC.player=self.avPlayer;

    [self addChildViewController:self.avPlayerViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:self.avPlayerViewController.view];
    self.avPlayerViewController.view.frame=self.view.frame;
    [self.avPlayerViewController.player play];
   }
```

**The image of the video with control buttons:** [image]