# Can't swipe the UIScrollView when AVPlayer is running

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Hi everyone I am trying to swipe between two pages through a scrollview and it works fine but when I try to swipe while a video is playing it won't work here is my code for my ViewControllers

MainVeiwController

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scrollView.isPagingEnabled=true
        let settings = SettingsViewController(nibName: "SettingsViewController", bundle: nil)
        self.addChildViewController(settings)
        self.scrollView.addSubview(settings.view)
        settings.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

        let diamond = DiamondViewController(nibName: "DiamondViewController", bundle: nil)
        var frame1 = diamond.view.frame
        frame1.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width
        diamond.view.frame=frame1
        self.addChildViewController(diamond)
        self.scrollView.addSubview(diamond.view)
        diamond.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width * 2, height: self.view.frame.size.height-70)
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: scrollView.frame.size.width, y: 0)
}
```

Second ViewController

```
var playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
var playerView = AVPlayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "PATHTOVIDEO")
    playerView=AVPlayer(url: fileURL as URL)

    playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls=false;

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: playerView.currentItem, queue: nil)
    { notification in
        let t1 = CMTimeMake(1, 100);
        self.playerView.seek(to: t1)
        self.playerView.play()

    }


    playerViewController.player = playerView

    self.present(playerViewController,animated:true){
        self.playerViewController.player?.play()
    }
}
```

Now what I want to know is how can I swipe between the pages even though the video is playing is there a workaround or something

Comment: I think that the problem is the `swipeRight` gesture recognizer that you add on your second view controller. In my opinion it captures the touch and doesn't make the scrollview handle it.

Comment: that part was just to try it out otherwise it doesn't work in either way when the video is playing

Comment: Ok.
The problem is that you are presenting the `playerViewController`, then when you are playing the video you are in a new `UIWindow` and you have not anymore the touch on the old window.

Comment: Thank you Franco Meloni, your help combined with the help of the below answer I found out how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to embed your `AVPlayerViewController` in your SecondViewController instead of presenting it.

Code Example:

```
let url = // whatever
let player = AVPlayer(URL:url)
let av = AVPlayerViewController()
av.player = player
av.view.frame = // whatever
self.addChildViewController(av)
self.view.addSubview(av.view)
av.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

Code from: 
[AVPlayer with playback controls of avplayerviewcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33677527/avplayer-with-playback-controls-of-avplayerviewcontroller)

Comment: I added your code to the scrollview as a subview and it worked like charm