# Adding ScrollView under video frame

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

I have a video frame on top of Main.storyboard and I put ScrollView with TextView under that, now my problem is the ScrollView is not in the same position on all devices.

For example, in iPhone 7 Plus its in the correct position but in the iPhone SE its different same iPad.

Here is my ViewController.swift code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    var player:AVPlayer?

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let videoString:String? = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "m9", ofType: ".mov")

        playerController.player = player
        self.addChildViewController(playerController)
        let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
        let videoFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 30, width: screenSize.width, height: (screenSize.width * 9) / 16 )
        playerController.view.frame = videoFrame
        self.view.addSubview(playerController.view)
        player?.play()
```

Then I tried to link the ScrollView to video frame:

```
let frame1 = CGRect(x: 0, y:  350 + videoFrame.height , width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height)

textView.frame = frame1
```

Comment: Why the empty lines and stuff that has nothing to do with your question?

Answer (score 0):

Just make the outlet of your scrollview and set its frame like :

```
let scrollViewFrame= CGRect(x: 0, y: playerController.view.frame.maxY, width: screenSize.width, height: replace_actual_height)
scrollView.frame = scrollViewFrame
```

However, it is better to use autolayout for that rather than setting frames. Here is the link.

[Understanding Autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

This code works perfectly in the scroll view. Simple scrollview add in avplayerviewcontoller then don't swipe so replace this code...

```
 let url = // whatever
 let player = AVPlayer(URL:url)
 let av = AVPlayerViewController()
 av.player = player
 av.view.frame = // whatever
 self.addChildViewController(av)
 self.view.addSubview(av.view)
 av.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

Code is [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33677527/avplayer-with-playback-controls-of-avplayerviewcontroller)