# iOS/Swift: How to add share button in the playbackControls of a AVPlayerViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayerviewcontroller

I would like to add a share button to share a video (by mail for example) with the [UIActivityController](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=do1EF3CoO8M&t=206s).

I tried to access to the properties of the AVPlayerViewController, but it seems we are not allowed to it anymore...

```
for subview in playerViewController.view.subviews 
    {
    }
```

How to add a simple button next to the play button on the right in the playbackControls?

Any ideas?

Comment: I dont think you can do that, you need to create your own controls

Comment: @Scriptable i agree.

Comment: @Scriptable If I do like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/33677661/3581620 do you think this will work the same way (one tap makes the controls visible, second tap makes it disappear, etc...)?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the view controller's view's subviews, you will see its a single view called `AVPlayerViewControllerContentView`. You can do something like this when making your view controller:

```swift
func showFullScreenVideo(using player: AVPlayer) {
    // setup your player view controller
    let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerViewController.player = player
    present(playerViewController, animated: true) { [weak self] in
      self?.addShareButton(to: playerViewController)
    }
}

private func addShareButton(to playerViewController: AVPlayerViewController) {
    if let playerContentView = playerViewController.view.subviews.first {
        let someView = SomeView()
        playerContentView.addSubview(someView)
        // use your own layout code:
        someView.constrain(.centerX, .centerY, to: playerContentView)
    }
}
```

Adding the share button inside the completion block ensures that `playerViewController.view` is loaded and available to use. You can *try* to force the view to load in many ways. The choice is yours. Another *possible* way of doing this is adding this line of code just before adding your share button:

`_ = playerViewController.view`

instead of using the completion block. May or may not work, but the completion block method definitely works.